# Sampling distribution of the Pearson correlation of not necessarily normally distributed variables

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, correlation

Does anyone know how to compute the sampling distribution of the Pearson correlation between two continuous IID random variables, given only the sample size $n$ and the PDFs, CDFs, characteristic functions, or the like of the distribution?

Comment: By "identically", I assume you mean "independent and identically distributed"? Do you have a specific distribution in mind? I would assume this to be hard in the general case. Also, I assume you are thinking about continuous distributions?

Comment: Yes, I do mean (continuous) IID, I've edited the question for clarity. I've had Cauchy in mind, but would ideally like for the methodology to remain agnostic to the distribution. Are you aware of a general approach to such problems---ideally one that is suited to distributions without moments as well?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but it's an interesting question.

Comment: Clearly there is a distribution since the sample correlation is bounded between $0$ and $1$, and it will be more concentrated around $0$ as $n$ increases.  Simulation will work  such as using  R something like `corrsim <- function(FUN, n){ cor(FUN(n),FUN(n)) };` 
`plot(density(replicate(10^5, corrsim(rcauchy, 9)), from=-1, to=1), col="blue");` 
`lines(density(replicate(10^5, corrsim(rnorm, 9)), from=-1, to=1), col="red")`

Comment: That example suggests that for the Cauchy distribution you get both a higher peak density and wider tails the sample correlation than you would for a normal distribution with the same sample size $n=9$

Comment: In general, I'd be using simulation. In some specific cases of choice of  distribution choice it might be algebraically tractable (and the Cauchy may well be one of those).